# What is the difference between fread(&buffer...) and fread(buffer...)

Tags: c, buffer, fread

I'm trying to read from a file and copy it to another file. I am reviewing some codes online and I seem to notice that some declare fread this way:

```
fread (buffer, 1, 1000, src)
```

some this way

```
fread (&buffer, 1, 1000, src)
```

Let's say I have already declared this:

```
typedef uint8_t BYTE;
BYTE buffer[1000];
```

How would those two be different?

Comment: Same value, different type. When used as function argument, `buffer` is a pointer to `BYTE` while `&buffer` is a pointer to `BYTE[1000]`.

Comment: If `buffer` is an array they have the same value but different type. If `buffer` is a pointer they have different values.

Comment: I forgot to place. I have typedeffed BYTE as a datatype.

Comment: `fread (&buffer, 1, 1000, src)` is usually wrong when `buffer` is an array or a pointer. It is right, for say `char byt; fread(&byt, sizeof byt, 1, src);`

Comment: Oh. I see. I get it now. Thanks!

Comment: So just checking if I have it right. I don't do &buffer if buffer is an array or pointer because buffer in that case is already storing an address.

Comment: So just checking if I have it right. I don't do &buffer if buffer is an array or pointer because buffer in that case is already storing an address.

Comment: `buffer` is not **storing** an address. Instead `buffer` **is** an address

Comment: @MTiz While you are correct about **not** using `&buffer` and you are correct about the case where `buffer` is a pointer, your explanation isn't strictly correct for the array case. The more correct explanation is that when an array is used in an expression, it will in most cases be implicit converted to a pointer to the first element (a few exceptions exists). But for any practical use... yes, avoid `&` and the array will automatical be converted to a pointer with the correct value.

Comment: Thanks! I'm really confused with arrays being pointers but I have an idea already that it is a pointer to the first element. Thank you for the answers!

Comment: Thanks! I'm really confused with arrays being pointers but I have an idea already that it is a pointer to the first element. Thank you for the answers!

Comment: An array *isn't* a pointer, but when you refer to the name of an array, it decays to a pointer to its first element. That's why we do `scanf("%c", &chr)` but `scanf("%s", str);`

Answer (score 2):

`&buffer` returns a pointer to the array. The pointer has type `BYTE (*)[1000]`.

When an array is used where a pointer is expected, it degenerates into a pointer to its first element, so `buffer` is equivalent to `&(buffer[0])` in this situation. The pointer has type `BYTE*`.

Both pointers point to the same address.

Comment: Can you explain what happens on `&buffer+1` and `buffer+1`?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie That's a different question and should be posted as a separate one. Though I strongly suspect there are already lots of duplicates for it.

Comment: `p+1` will advance the pointer by the size of the thing pointed (`sizeof(*p)`). If you apply what I explained in my answer, you'll realize they are very different.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, there is no difference. The specification for `fread` is (C17 7.21.8.1):

> ```c
>    size_t fread(void * restrict ptr,
>    size_t size, size_t nmemb,
>    FILE * restrict stream);
> ```
>
> The fread function reads, into the array pointed to by ptr...

- `buffer` when used in an expression "decays" into a pointer to the first element. It will become type `uint8_t*` pointing at `buffer[0]`.
- `&buffer` takes the address of the array and an expression with `&` as operator to an array will not make it "decay". The resulting type is a pointer to array, `uint8 (*)[1000]`, which points at the address where the array begins. Which is also where `buffer[0]` is stored, so it is the same one as above.

Either of these will give the same address and either will work, as far as `fread` is concerned. Reading the standard pedantically, `&buffer` is actually more correct.

---

Unrelated to your question, `typedef uint8_t BYTE;` is horrible practice. Don't invent your own language with typedefs - by doing so you only make your code strange and less readable. Stick to the standard types as already available from `stdint.h`.